# Generating iid variates in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, probability

I am working on a question and it reads:

Generate 1000 iid variates of X=(x1, x2) with a specific definition that is given in an example. The definition is that x1 is a standard normal distribution so N(0,1). However x2 is approximately x1 when -1 <= x1 <=1 and is x1 otherwise.

[image]

I have used the following code to generate bi variate random variables before in R but I do not know how to to get `X=(x1, x2)` and then plot.

```
library(gplots)
n<-10^6
sigma<- matrix(c(4,2,2,3), ncol=2)
x<- rmvnorm(n, mean = c(1,2), sigma = sigma)
h2d<- hist2d(x, show = FALSE, same.scale = TRUE, nbins = c(40,40))
persp(h2d$x, h2d$y, h2d$counts/n, ticktype="detailed", theta=30, phi=30, expand=0.5, shade=0.5, col="cyan", ltheta=-30,main="Bivariate Normal Distribution", zlab="f(x1,x2)",xlab="x1",ylab="x2")
```

So I know the above is not correct but I am not sure if I can do something similar or I am going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than you think:

```
set.seed(1) # Setting a seed
X1 <- rnorm(1000) # Simulating X1
X2 <- ifelse(abs(X1) <= 1, -X1, X1) # If abs(X1) <= 1, then set X2=-X1 and X2=X1 otherwise.
```

Since the question is about normal marginals but not normal bivariate distribution, we may look at a bivariate density estimate:

```
library(MASS)
image(kde2d(X1,X2))
```

[image]

Clearly the shape is not an ellipsoid, so the bivariate distribution is not normal even though both marginals are normal.

It can also be seen analytically. Let Z=X1+X2. If (X1,X2) was bivariate normal, then Z also would be normal. But P(Z = 0) >= P(|X1| <= 1) ~= 0.68, i.e., it has positive mass at zero, which cannot be the case with a continuous distribution.

Comment: See I feel like that symbol in the definition is not a negative sign but I suppose it makes much more sense if it is.

Comment: @Derek, I can't imagine what else it could be (it may be ~ but that would be a poor notation). And given the question about nonnormality it indeed makes perfect sense and gives a nice counterexample. See the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rnorm` base function to generate the normal distribution. And, using simple `ifelse` function we can get x2, shown below:

```
x1 <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
x2 <- ifelse( ((x1 <= 1) & (x1 >= -1)), -x1, x1)
plot(x1, x2, type='p')
```

[image]

Comment: So I guess what I am having an issue with is that the question says X2 is approximately X1 when -1<=X1<=1 and X1 otherwise. So in the code that you just provided X2 is a vector of 0's and 1's based on the condition but I feel like that is incorrect, no?

Comment: oh sorry, I just noticed that, My bad. 0 needs to be replaced with X1 but what about 1 ? Can you define 'X2 is approximately X1' ?

Comment: See that is where I too am confused. I'll add a picture of the definition to the question but that is all it says. Or at least that is how I am reading it.

Comment: Thanks I've updated the answer. It means X2 is -X1 given the condition else X1.